# Which machine learning algorithm should i use to predict if particular parking space will be occupied?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, data-science, iot

I'm working on my idea for Master thesis topic.
I get a dataset with milions of records which describe on-street parking sensors.

Data i have :
-vehicle present on particular sensor ( true  or false)
It's normal that there are few parking event where there are False values with different duration time in a row.

-arrival time and departure time(month,day,hour,minute and even second)
-duration in minutes

And few more columns, but i don't have any idea how to show in my analysis that "continuity of time" and
reflect this in the calculations for a certain future time based on the time when the parking space was usually free or occupied.

Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to consider more factors, those eventually will be related to humans' decision to park at a certain spot. Eg: location of spot to entry or exit point, where is the payment booth etc. Give more details about the available features for this problem. Every sensor must be having a fixed spot in the parking lot. Describe dataset in more extensive way. The sensors must be making observations at fixed interval. I guess you already have a time series based data. Give a sample of the data itself if possible. Are you trying to develop some recommender system for incoming cars to be parked?

Comment: That's dataset : https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/Transport/On-street-Car-Parking-Sensor-Data-2019/7pgd-bdf2      When we will sort vales by deviceid and arrivaltime then we can see that even if for example: True value for vehiclepresent will be at 13:00 for 15 minutes, then we can notice False value for 13:15-13:13:40, and then again False value for 13:40-13:50. My problem is with this, because i can't image if any model can think...okay this sensor can have a lot of time when there's no car. But still hard to make such feature that can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can take two approaches:

1. If you want to predict whether a particular space will be occupied or not and if you take in count order of the events (TIME), this seems like a time series problem. You should start by trying simple time-series algorithms like Moving average or [ARIMA Models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average). There are more sophisticated methods that take in count long and short term relationships, like recurrent neural networks, especially [LSTM (Long short-term memory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) which have shown good performance in time series problems.
2. You can take in the count all variables and use them to train a clustering algorithm like K-means or SVM.

As you pointed out:

> And few more columns, but I don't have any idea how to show in my analysis that "continuity of time" and reflect this in the calculations for a certain future time based on the time when the parking space was usually free or occupied.

I recommend you to work this problem as a time series problem.

Answer (score 0):

Timeseries modeling will be better option for this kind of modelling. As you said you want to predict binary output at different time intervals i.e whether the the parking slot will be occupied at the particular time interval or not. You can use LSTM for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Time series is definitely an option here... if you are really going with LSTMs why not look into Transformers and take advantage of attention mechanism while doing time series forecasting !! I don't know them thoroughly, yet, just have a vague idea and performance benefits over RNNs and LSTM.